# Why do i get this error when i do a SELECT..INSERT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why do i get this error

> `The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.`

When i run this query

```
INSERT INTO TempOutputOfGroupifySP
    (MonthOfQuery,Associate,[NoOfClaims],[ActualNoOfLines],[AverageTATInDays],
    [NoOfErrorsDiscovered],[VarianceinPercent],[NoOfClaimsAudited],[InternalQualInPercent],[ExternalQualInPercent]
    )

SELECT (DATENAME(MONTH,[ClaimProcessedDate])) AS MonthOfQuery,
    Temp.Associate AS Associate,
    COUNT(*) AS [NoOfClaims],
    SUM(NoOfLines) AS [ActualNoOfLines] ,
    (SUM(DATEDIFF(dd,[ClaimReceivedDate],[ClaimProcessedDate]))/COUNT(*))  AS [AverageTATInDays],
    A.[NoOfErrorsDiscovered] AS [NoOfErrorsDiscovered],
    Temp.[MonthlyTarget] As [TargetNoOfLines],(Temp.[MonthlyTarget] - COUNT(*)) AS [VarianceInPercent],
    B.[NoOfClaimsAudited] AS [NoOfClaimsAudited],
    ((A.[NoOfErrorsDiscovered]/NULLIF(B.[NoOfClaimsAudited],0))*100) AS [InternalQualInPercent],
    NULL AS [ExternalQualInPercent]
    FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [NoOfErrorsDiscovered] FROM TempTableForStatisticsOfAssociates T1 WHERE [TypeOfError] IS NOT NULL) AS A, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [NoOfClaimsAudited] FROM TempTableForStatisticsOfAssociates T2 WHERE Auditor IS NOT NULL) AS B,
    TempTableForStatisticsOfAssociates Temp
    GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,([ClaimProcessedDate])),
    Temp.Associate,
    A.[NoOfErrorsDiscovered],
    Temp.[MonthlyTarget],
    B.[NoOfClaimsAudited]
```

Strucuture of the target table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempOutputOfGroupifySP](
    [MonthOfQuery] [nchar](10) NULL,
    [Associate] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [NoOfClaims] [int] NULL,
    [ActualNoOfLines] [int] NULL,
    [AverageTATInDays] [int] NULL,
    [NoOfErrorsDiscovered] [int] NULL,
    [VarianceInPercent] [float] NULL,
    [NoOfClaimsAudited] [int] NULL,
    [InternalQualInPercent] [float] NULL,
    [ExternalQualInPercent] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: It may be because you've 10 colomns in your `INSERT` statement and you return 11 columns in your `SELECT` statement...

Comment: You are selecting 11 items and inserting 9 items only

Comment: Sorry i realized i have missed TargetNoOfLines. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `INSERT INTO` defines 10 colums for the insertion, however, your `SELECT` statement return 11 columns. You are either missing a column in your `INSERT` statement or returning one too many in your `SELECT` statement.
Comparing your table structure and your `SELECT` and `INSERT` the following line in your `SELECT` statement doesn't have a counterpart:

```
Temp.[MonthlyTarget] As [TargetNoOfLines]
```